# for loop and generating random panel data

Tags: r, for-loop, statistics, regression, nested-for-loop

I want to generate a panel data sets with 5 units and 10 observations in r and get the test statistics. However, my problem here is to do this process 1000 times. For each id I need to restart the cumsum argument again for randomness. I want to create 1000 random data sets by providing randomness in each unit separately and apply adf.test to them 1000 times. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
library(tseries)
set.seed(123)
result <- NULL
for (i in 1:1000) {
  n_entities <- 5
  n_years <- 10
  id <- rep(1:n_entities, each = n_years)
  year <- rep(2000:2009, times = n_entities)
  value <- cumsum(rnorm(n_entities * n_years))
  data <- data.frame(id = id, Year = year, Value = value)
  result [i] = adf.test(data$Value)$statistic
}
```

I tried to edit it with different codes, but I realized that the data set does not get the cumulative sum for each unit (n_entities) again. I need to generate a cumulative random data set for each unit in turn, rather than setting the size and filling it with data.

Comment: If you want a length-50 vector made from concatenating together 5 vectors of cumulative sums of a random variable, try `c(replicate(n_entities, cumsum(rnorm(n_years))))`

Comment: In fact, we can think of it as 5 random data sets. To ensure randomness, I want to take the cumulative sum from the first row in each unit. So it will be necessary to take the cumulative sum 5 times.

Comment: Yes, that's what this code does.

Comment: unfortunately when I examine the result I see the same values

Comment: Possibly a lazy evaluation issue. Do you see the same problem if you use `lapply` rather than `for`?

Comment: yes same values again

Comment: Unable to reproduce.  replacing the final line of the loop with `result[i] <- mean(data$Value)` (I don't have the `tseries` package), I get ten different `result`s.

Comment: There is no problem to get 10 different results. The code does not generate cumulative random data for each unit over and over again during the data generation process.

Answer (score 0):

Using Allan's suggestion, and cleaning up a little

```
set.seed(123)
n_entities <- 5
n_years <- 10
id <- rep(1:n_entities, each = n_years)
year <- rep(2000+(1:n_years)-1, times = n_entities)

result <- replicate(100, {
    value <- c(replicate(n_entities, cumsum(rnorm(n_years))))
    data.frame(id = id, Year = year, Value = value)
}, simplify=FALSE)

lapply(result[1:2], "[", 8:12, 1:3)
# [[1]]
#    id Year      Value
# 8   1 2007 1.87877126
# 9   1 2008 1.19191841
# 10  1 2009 0.74625644
# 11  2 2000 1.22408180
# 12  2 2001 1.58389562
# 
# [[2]]
#    id Year       Value
# 8   1 2007  1.87706415
# 9   1 2008  2.00091839
# 10  1 2009  2.21685996
# 11  2 2000  0.37963948
# 12  2 2001 -0.12268397
# 

adf_stat <- sapply(result, function(x) adf.test(x$Value)$statistic)
adf_stat[1:4]
# Dickey-Fuller Dickey-Fuller Dickey-Fuller Dickey-Fuller 
#    -2.6577763    -1.5253793    -1.4580183    -2.8355005
```

For a simple function that does this basic thing…

```
adf_sim <- function(n_entities=5, n_years=10, reps=1e2, year1=2000){
    id <- rep(1:n_entities, each=n_years)
    year <- rep(year1+(1:n_years)-1, times=n_entities)
    replicate(reps, {
        adf.test(c(replicate(n_entities, cumsum(rnorm(n_years)))))$statistic
    })
}

set.seed(123)
adf_sim()[1:4]
# Dickey-Fuller Dickey-Fuller Dickey-Fuller Dickey-Fuller 
#    -2.6577763    -1.5253793    -1.4580183    -2.8355005
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your contribution. Actually, I think it would be good to use two nested for loops to generalize the code and turn it into a function, but I could not get the correct results here.

Comment: @bbkl: One advantage of not nesting the loops is that if you want to return anything else than the test statistic, you can do so without re-running the outer loop. If you want a function that only returns the statistic, the code can be simplified greatly. I added one approach.